# Multiple Angular 9 Route Resolvers creates error "Error: Uncaught (in promise): EmptyError: no elements in sequence"

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Can anyone tell me why i get this error when trying to use multiple Resolvers in Angular routing. If remove either the route resolves. But when I include both i get the error

[image]
[image][image]
[image]

Comment: What do the resolvers look like ?

Comment: @AndreiGătej Just added pics.

Comment: You have to make sure that your resolver returns **at least** one value before completes! For a 'dummy' test, try to do `subscriber.next('foo')` just  before `subscriber.complete()`.

Comment: @AndreiGătej can you please add the answer so i can mark as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that your resolver returns at least one value before completes! For a 'dummy' test, try to do `subscriber.next('foo')` just before `subscriber.complete()`.